# Dynamic SQL Connection Class From Config

Tags: c#, ado.net, config

What's up.
Is there any implemented code for saving connection string part by part in the config file and use it in the application?
Also, put some defaults value in hard code ?

Comment: Stuff like connections strings should not be stored on the client side. Unless there is a seperate SQL User for each enduser, this is just a giant danger to happen. A common trick is to add a abstraction layer. Something like a WebService the application talks too. Something you can run on the server side, where this information is way harder to get.

Comment: Good point Christopher, Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I implement it a long time ago.
**App.Config or Web.Config :**

```
<userSettings>
    <ApartmentManagementSystem.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="DataSource" serializeAs="String">
        <value>(local)</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="InitialCatalog" serializeAs="String">
        <value>ApartmentManagementSystem</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="IntegratedSecurity" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ConnectTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>5</value>
      </setting>
    </ApartmentManagementSystem.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

**Connection Class (static)**

```
public static class ConnectionString
    {
        public static string DataSource { get; set; }
        public static string InitialCatalog { get; set; }
        public static Boolean IntegratedSecurity { get; set; }
        public static string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public static int ConnectTimeout { get; set; }


        static ConnectionString()
        {
            DataSource = Settings.Default.DataSource ?? @"(local)";
            InitialCatalog = Settings.Default.InitialCatalog ?? @"ApartmentManagementSystem";
            IntegratedSecurity = Settings.Default.IntegratedSecurity;
            ApplicationName = Settings.Default.ApplicationName ?? System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
            ConnectTimeout = Settings.Default.ConnectTimeout;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// fetch default sql connection from settings
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Connection String</returns>
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            var _connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                DataSource = ConnectionString.DataSource,
                InitialCatalog = ConnectionString.InitialCatalog,
                IntegratedSecurity = ConnectionString.IntegratedSecurity,
                ApplicationName = ConnectionString.ApplicationName,
                ConnectTimeout = ConnectionString.ConnectTimeout
            };
            return _connection.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, you can test your connection :
try
{
    connection.Open();
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) return true;
    else return false;
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx) 
    return false;

Comment: Thanks bro; 
what is : System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])

Comment: Its using file name without extension for application name in connection, logging purpose.